# How do I use a wild card certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, certificate, wildcard

I received a wild card certificate from my customer. It contained three files:

- something.crt
- something.pem
- gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

The last one is a bundle of cert keys.
Previously, I always created my own private key to sign, but I do not know how to deal with this.

I use openssl and NginX on this site.

Is it possible to sign my own created key using this cert or should I ask for the private key which is the base of this cert?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to sign my own created key using this cert ...

No

> ... or should I ask for the private key which is the base of this cert?

If you are supposed to setup a server with this certificate then you need the private key. It is unknown if the key is part of the send files since you only provide file names and the content of the actual files is unknown. Specifically it is unknown what `something.pem` contains or of `something.*` contains both certificate and key (which is possible with PEM format). But if the key is not there then you need to ask the customer for the key.

Comment: It looks to be also some certificate. (-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----). I don't know whether it may contain a private key.

Comment: @FERcsI: If the is no line with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` or similar then there was no private key given.